# Unterschied zwischen "Was ist eine ´Universität´" und "Was bitte ist eine ´Universität´"

Tags: difference

Manchmal sehe (oder höre) Ich, dass der Muttersprachler `Was bitte` anstatt vom `Was` benutzt. Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Fragen und falls ja, was ist er?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diese Art, eine Frage einzuleiten, klingt stark nach Sarkasmus, Ungeduld, Verwunderung oder Unverständnis. Wie ich es oft gerne tue, würde ich auch hier anhand von Beispielen zeigen, wie man diese rhetorische Figur eventuell nutzen könnte.

> Den Selfie-Wahnsinn halte ich für übertrieben und abnormal, aber was ist bitte schön heutzutage noch normal?
>
> Was bitte soll diese komische Schreibweise *LehrerInnen* bedeuten?
>
> *Für Aufsehen sorgen vor allem diese drei Buchstaben: FDJ. (...) Fast kein Zuschauer der EM versteht es: Was, bitte, bedeuten diese 3 Buchstaben?* ([Quelle](http://www.focus.de/sport/videos/seltsame-stadionwerbung-fast-kein-zuschauer-der-em-versteht-es-was-bitte-bedeuten-diese-3-buchstaben_id_5684484.html))
>
> -Mama, ich werde mich piercen lassen. - Was sagst du da bitte?!
>
> Wann bitte wird endlich diese kaputte Straße repariert?

Solltest du Schwierigkeiten haben, die Rolle des *bitte* in diesem Zusammenhang nachzuvollziehen, könnte das folgende Meme helfen. Auch auf Deutsch hätte man gesagt *Bitte!* oder *Ich bitte dich!*, um diese Emotion auszudrücken. Die Überleitung zu dem eingangs gesagten ist dann fließend.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In meinem Sprachgefühl zeigt `Was bitte` ein größeres Erstaunen oder größeres Unverständnis. Vergleichbar mit dem englischen `What the hell is a university` im Vergleich zu `What is a university`.

Comment: Ich habe einen Satz auf der Straße gesehen. Was bitte ist ein Bookstore? Ich denke nicht, in diesem Fall bedeutet es "What the hell is a bookstore" :) oder ?